# OAuth client id and guessing

Tags: oauth, clientid, phishing

OAuth manual https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/ says that

> The client_id is a public identifier for apps. Even though it’s
> public, it’s best that it isn’t guessable by third parties, so many
> implementations use something like a 32-character hex string. It must
> also be unique across all clients that the authorization server
> handles. If the client ID is guessable, it makes it slightly easier to
> craft phishing attacks against arbitrary applications.

Why should I care about client-id guessing? It is public. Anyone can read it. Why should I make it hex string?

Can I have own oauth provider that has only few client ids, e.g. app1, app2, app3. I will use PKCE and server redirect to well known urls only.

How that is vulnerable to phishing having such short client-id values?

Comment: The text uses the word 'slightly', and you ask if it's 'so bad', so just based on this I would say: 'No, it's probably not _that bad_, just slightly ;)'